# Is there a hashing algorithm that allows me to specify output character length?

Tags: encryption, hashing, algorithm

My security officer is looking for a hashing algorithm that will take a string of up to 20 characters, and then output a unique, 12-character alphanumeric hash. The 20-character string is generally just going to be numbers (okay, I'll tell you, it's credit card numbers) so it seems compressible to me.

Probably he'd have more of a comfort level if it's something that's publicly available and tested, but my research thus far suggests that popular hashing algorithms have generally fixed length outputs (or variable outputs, but to specific predetermined lengths).

Comment: While you want to hide context, I would like to ask you to provide more context as your question is in no way constructive. Make sure that the title actually matches the body of your question. Why are you operating on the credit card number? Have you [researched](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) hashing, credit card numbers and the standards and laws that apply to them? Which exact problem are you having when trying to implement a solution? The answer to your question title is "yes", all the rest in this Q&A is mostly not constructive... Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Watch out](http://www.integrigy.com/security-resources/whitepapers/Integrigy_Hashing_Credit_Card_Numbers_Unsafe_Practices.pdf) when you handle credit card numbers!

Just adhere to the standards and laws that apply in your area, or are given by your security officer. If you really need to do this then make sure that you reconsider your design, you really don't want to pass a credit card number around your code or have credit card numbers collide because of hashing.

That's asking for trouble sooner or later...

A credit card number should have a very short time to live in your code, use it for the payment and no more than that. At best you can store a trimmed version of it, for display purposes only. But don't use it in cases were its hashes would collide or in a way that the original can be retrieved, and if you somehow really need to do so make sure you have a good hashing and/or security system, that no collisions are possible and you are able to contact all customers when your database / software security has been breached.

Comment: What does "do never literally hash" mean?

Oh and by the way, I don't want a decryption algorithm, that's why I said hashing rather than encryption. It's intended (in fact, required) to be one-way.

Comment: What good is the hash if it's one-way?  It's a security liability if the hash is discovered to be weak, and useless otherwise.

Comment: @spinn: I would really advise you to [read up on hashing credit card numbers](http://www.integrigy.com/security-resources/whitepapers/Integrigy_Hashing_Credit_Card_Numbers_Unsafe_Practices.pdf). If you do it wrong you'll end up with an easy to find credit card numbers as a result, you could of course go one-way but then you would be throwing data away which just makes brute forcing easier...

Comment: The idea of having the hash is so we have a token we can use internally, without actually passing the raw credit card numbers around our database. I get the impression that the token would be used to match and identify the actual credit card elsewhere in a significantly more secure area. Yes, possible path of entry blah blah blah, but I'm not trying to solve all my SO's problems here, I'm just trying to help him out with the question he asked me.

Comment: @spinn: Why would you have to pass around credit card numbers if you can use integer IDs as primary keys? Why would you match by credit card and not by the user who used that credit card?

Comment: Don't know; you want to ask him?

Comment: @spinn: Uhm, the only thing he has to do with this is telling you to follow standard X or law Y, that's where the task of the security officer stops. From there on the rest is all you; so, I am asking you *why would you do that* and why would you choose for a *12-character alhanumeric hash*, is that according to standard X or law Y? Please reconsider your database design as well as verifying whether you adhere to what is given...

Comment: hm. Next time I ask, I'll just say "20 numbers", I guess. Clearly I've inserted too much distraction.

Comment: @spinn: If you read Tom's link you'll get your answer there: Use a very large salt (4KB was suggested), use the best one-way hash algorithm available, hash multiple times (100 suggested), don't store the last four digits of the original number anywhere it can be associated with the hash. I believe the usual solution for custom length hashes is to generate a longer one and use it's last n digits.

Comment: @spinn - Why are you even here if you don't want to know the correct way to do this task?

Comment: @Ramhound - Oh I do, obviously. But while I agree that there are further worries around the fact that he's doing operations on credit card numbers, and he should be asked questions like "why are you doing this", the fact is, that's not the question I asked. I should've just asked how I hash 20 numbers down to 12 and leave it there, is my point. It seems like a lot of assumptions are being made around my question or the roles of people unknown to the public that are creating noise in the responses.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - that was actually one of the questions he asked me originally: if he just truncates a hash, doesn't that mean we can't guarantee there's no collision?

Comment: @spinn You never had such a guarantee in the first place. "In the context of cryptographic hash functions, the inability of an adversary to compute collisions efficiently is often essential to the security of the protocol. A collision-free hash function is a type of one-way function that formalizes this property: it is not possible for a randomized polynomial-time algorithm to locate a collision of a collision-free hash function with non-negligible probability. **It is unknown whether such a function exists**." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science))

Comment: @spinn: Under the context of hashing, you'll *always* end up with a domain that's smaller than the original domain. A simple example is just taking the hash of a file, the hash is short while the file can be of any size. There's no one-to-one mapping there, hence you always have the chance on collisions, **which you really don't want to see when credit cards are involved**. When you instead just turn something longer into something shorter in such a way that you can get the longer version from the shorter version, we're talking about compression and/or encryption. No collisions there...

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason for a merchant to store a full credit card number, hashed or not.

I think you really need to evaluate why you need to do this.

If you're storing credit card numbers, the number space may be small enough that brute-forcing the hash is plausible, making storing even this hash dangerous and probably in violation of PCI.

There's almost certainly a better solution that's going to allow you to solve the real problem you're facing.

Comment: Don't they need the full credit card number to do automated subscriptions? Like for example when you play World of Warcraft and don't have to touch your billing anymore because it goes automatically...

Comment: There is no point into brute-forcing the hash as you can't use the hash to do something; if the hash were actually a one-to-one mapping then it would just be equivalent to brute forcing the credit card number itself. But indeed, credit card numbers should be handled with great attention to legal stuff...

Comment: The merchant?  I don't think so, no.  That can be handled by the payment processor.  The merchant only needs to store an ID received from the processor.

Comment: @TomWijsman: If you can brute force the hash, you've got a list of known-good credit card numbers.

Comment: Well, to make it clear, it's up to my security officer to need to evaluate why he's doing this. I can pass concerns along, but I'm just answering the question about technical possibility. But he's always dealing with PCI compliance, so he's going to be mindful of the issues. (I hope.)

Comment: Then don't hash the credit card number, use a high quality PRNG to generate a random token.

Comment: @Spinn - If you have a concern, verify it will break PCI compliance, then bring up that concern to your security officer. I strongly suggest you refuse to do ANYTHING that YOU KNOW WILL NOT be secure.  YOU will be blamed when something happens, despite the fact you said something, their response will be "speak louder next time"

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for your concern, but seriously, you have no detail about my work or company or the significance-or-not of the question I'm asking. I do appreciate the help and responses, really, but I feel like I'm getting lectured here for things that don't apply to my life. I mean we're three steps away from telling me I need to manage my finances better, and maybe I should be paying more attention to my wife?

Comment: @spinn: How do you expect "I mean we're three steps away from telling me I need to manage my finances better, and maybe I should be paying more attention to my wife?" to yield you any better answers? We're just making assumptions because of a lack of context, if they're wrong that's not our fault...

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a 20-digit number, then there are 10<sup>20</sup> possible inputs.
If your output is a 12 character alphanumeric string, then there are 62<sup>12</sup> possible outputs.

**Inputs:**

```
100000000000000000000
```

**Outputs:**

```
3226266762397899821056
```

If we look closely, we see the bottom number is longer.
Which means there are [more possible outputs than inputs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare+10%5E20+and+62%5E12).
Which means the hashing is pointless as every possible output can be mapped directly to one input. So that means it would be incredibly easy to break and get the actual numbers back.

> So, we'll just use a shorter hash!

What's the point? Just use an integer, a random one if you have to.

---

Let's take passwords as an example.
You never store a password. You only store the hash. That makes it easy to check a given input against that hash (to see if the provided password is correct) without ever storing the actual password.

This works because:

1. our hashing algorithms don't produce the same hash for two inputs easily (collisions
   unlikely)
2. it is unreasonable to assume that someone could figure out the original input for a given hash

And why is that? Well, the password I used could be 1,000,000 characters long. How are you gonna figure that out from a short hash? You can't. You can only try to calculate as many hashes as you can, compare them to the one you have and hope for a match. In this case it usually isn't even relevant to find the actual, original input as any input that produces the same hash will work.

So, if I'm an attacker and I got a hold of the database with the hashes, I could compare the hashes to a set I [previously computed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to find a valid input for that hash. This is usually countered by *salting* your hashes.

So an attacker would be forced to brute-force so long until he found a valid input for a matching hash (which would take forever, because there's an insane amount of possible hashes).

But what if the passwords were limited to a certain length and they could only contain numbers?
This drastically reduces the possible inputs and, thus, the time it would take to brute-force a matching hash.
And that's basically what you're doing when hashing credit card numbers. But it's worse because if the attacker got a match, then it's not just going to be an arbitrary string but, most likely, a valid credit card number!

Comment: Wouldn't you have to compute all 100000000000000000000 hashes to be *certain* of finding which 20-digit number produced a particular 12 character string?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, What happens if there is a collision?  (Two numbers that result in the same hash)?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, but every hit time you calculate a hash that exists in the database, you have a valid CC number (worth it). And there aren't actually that many valid numbers. By knowing what CC numbers are valid, you can trim the input down quite a bit.

Comment: @Zoredache: well that's even better, after computing 100000000000000000000 hashes you still don't know for certain which are valid CC numbers. However you are stating the opposite of Oliver who says there's a weakness because "every possible output can be mapped directly to one input" (no collisions).

Comment: @Oliver. OK but does that bring it into the realm of "incredibly easy"? How many orders of magnitude are we talking? Can we reduce it from 100000000000000000000 hash calcs to only 100000000000000000? more? less?. If we use a 4KB salt and 100-fold hashing with SHA-512 (as in Tom's ref) is it "incredibly easy"?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It's actually only 19 digits, 4 are used for issuer identification. Makes only 14 that really need to be brute-forced. Right? Then there is the Luhn check digit. Guess we don't need to include that either... It's easy in that there are bound to be a very low number of inputs for a given output. Otherwise there would have to be tons of collisions (which would mean the hashing algorithm sucks). If I can *only* reduce the possible, valid CC numbers for a person to 100, that's enough. But I get your point. "incredibly easy" might have been a poor choice of words.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I think saying "incredibly easy" is the perfect word to describe it.  Its "incredibly easy" if your dealing with a criminal organization that has unlimited funds ( hey its not their money in theory ) and a huge possible pay day.

Comment: @Ramhound: [Who could disagree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: "every possible output can be mapped directly to one input"...I thought that was what a hash was meant to be? I mean...apparently that's the problem with MD5, it's been demonstrated that two different documents can have the same MD5 checksum. (understand I am not disagreeing with you here, I suppose I'm just showing my ignorance.)

Comment: @spinn: No, a hash always involves loss of data. Oliver's example is not a hash but just a conversion of one representation to another, in which more numbers are available. Any hash has collisions, some performing better than others...

Comment: @spinn I updated my answer to hopefully explain my concerns better.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all of the questions above, there's a really, really, blindingly simple solution.

In pseudocode:

```
function my_hash(string data, int length){
    string t = md5sum(data);
    return t.substring(0,length)
}
```

Or sha512 sum or whatever strikes your fancy. Personally I recommend multiple rounds of blowfish. If someone grabs the database, and knows how you've created this hash, they can simple run through the space of all CC numbers as well and compare data to reverse it. This is **bad**.

However, beware. Read all of the other answers, they all have very valid points.

Comment: Also, for the love of all things good and holy, salt them well if you do this.